# JMenuBar does not appear in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, frame, menubar

**SOLVED** Forgot to instantiate my menuBar...

I have extended the class `JMenuBar`, and also the class `JFrame`. However, when I `setJMenuBar(menubar)`, the MenuBar does not appear in the `Frame` when testing.

Here's my code:
Class Frame:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame extends JFrame{

public static MenuBar menubar;

public Frame(){
    setTitle("LoL Teamcomps");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setJMenuBar(menubar);

}   

}
```

Class MenuBar:

```
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import com.lolteamcomps.code.components.MenuItem;

public class MenuBar extends JMenuBar{

public MenuBar(){
    JMenuItem players = new JMenuItem("Players");
    JMenuItem champions = new JMenuItem("Champions");
    JMenuItem newPlayer = new JMenuItem("Add new");
    JMenuItem newChampion = new JMenuItem("Add new");

    players.add(newPlayer);
    champions.add(newChampion);

    add(players);
    add(champions);


}

}
```

And in my function called in my main:

```
private static Frame frame = new Frame(); 

public static void CreateWindow(){
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);



}
```

Only an empty `frame` appears, with nothing in it. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: My own thought was that `setJMenuBar(menubar)` won't work, because `menubar` is not a `JMenuBar`, but `MenuBar extends JMenuBar`, so in fact it is a `JMenuBar`, right? Also, I don't get an error at this line, so I don't think that is the case. Just a thought.

Comment: You don't seem to be instantiating your menuBar

Comment: Yeah, I see now. Srry 'bout that, pretty dumb... Thanks though! @Ordous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate `MenuBar`

```
public  MenuBar menubar=new MenuBar();

public Frame(){
 ....
 setJMenuBar(menubar);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For a simple example, people often use inheritance (ie: `extends`) to reduce the amount of code people have to read; however, it is not good practice to use inheritance unless it absolutely makes sense. In Java, you can only use inheritance once and therefore, you should carefully consider if it is appropriate to extend a JFrame, or to extend a JMenu. Are you literally extending the features of a JFrame or a JMenu? If the answer is no, then you should be using an instance variable instead and instantiate it within your constructor.

For example:

```
public class MyApplication {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JMenu menu;

public MyApplication() {
    frame = new JFrame();

    ... // setup JFrame with layout and other elements

    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menu = new JMenu("File");

    menuBar.add(menu);

    ... // other setup

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```